# Mouse Click Events on JTable

Tags: java-8, java-7

I want to get the index of selected row when user double clicks on a row.

Here is my code:

```
tab.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

            int selectedRow = tab.getSelectedRow();

            try {
                String file = rows[selectedRow][2];
                String path = "C:\\Users\\raj kumar\\Gallery\\" + file;
                JLabel fileLable = new JLabel();
                fileLable.setBounds(500, 600, 300, 300);
                fileLable.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
                pan.add(fileLable);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the `tab.getSelectedRow()` returns `-1` even though I double clicked the row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know on which row your mouse points, but you ask which row is selected. So the simple solution is, instead of

```
int selectedRow = tab.getSelectedRow();
```

you can use

```
int row = tab.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
```

to get the wanted row. The `Event e` has every necessary information you need. The `e.getPoint()` returns the exact `Point` your cursor is currently located. And the `rowAtPoint()` should be self explaining.

This also makes sure that you only work with **one** row at a time, if this is important to you. I don't know how `getSelectedRow()` works if multiple rows are selected.